# what is the syns2index in lucene 4.5?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, wordnet

In lucene 3, it supports indexing of wordnet.
but it seems in lucene 4, there are no example of how to index wordnet(wordnet_prolog\wn_s.pl)
dose anyone know what's the equivalent of Syns2Index in lucene 4.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any direct alternative available for `Syns2Index` as entire contrib/wordnet has been discontinued with release of **Lucene 3.4**. But it seems they have merged some of the functionalities of `Syns2Index` into [`SynonymFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html), I don't know if these merges are carried forward in [`SysnonymFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html) for lucene 4.5. [This](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_4_0/changes/Contrib-Changes.html#3.4.0.new_features.list) is the official change log. hope you get what you are looking for.

**Update:**
for the purpose of Query parsing use [`WordnetSynonymParser`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/WordnetSynonymParser.html), and if you want to lookup synonyms of particular word i would suggest go for [`JAWS`](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html) which provides very good API for word search.

Comment: Thanks for the info, do you happen to know what's the replacement of wordnet after lucene 4?